# droptree field -Return data by language

Tags: content-editor, fieldtype

I used  droptree field to allow the content author to select news items, and the content author has a specific language for example (en), but I can not filters news by languages.
 is there any way to return English news (English version) only for English content authors?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create Language Based Roles in Role Manager and per item, you need to set the Language Read and Language Write for the particular Role. Follow this link: [Language Based Roles](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3798/language-based-roles)

Answer (score 0):

One option to do this could be as described here by Ben Golden / Szymon Kuzniak:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452260/sitecore-tree-list-datasource-versionexist

[How to filter items by language in Treelist field](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-to-filter-items-by-language-in-treelist-field)

**Essentially:**

- Create a DataView which will filter out items based on language,
  override the method to get the correct items and add config to use
  this.
- Create a Custom TreeList control which inherits from TreeList and uses the new DataView and register the new control in Sitecore

You would need to update your droptree field to then use this custom Treelist and perhaps add a validator so content editors can only select one item at a time though either using this approach:

http://www.benramey.com/2012/06/12/limit-selected-items-on-sitecore-multilist-field/ (The regex will likely be this though: ^({[^}]+}|?){0,1}$)

or a custom validator similar to these:

https://sitecorecorner.com/2014/08/18/sitecore-custom-field-validator

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969604/how-to-validate-a-sitecore-single-line-text-field-to-include-a-character-limit

Comment: my requirement allows authors to select only one item, therefore I can  not use Treelist , is there any way to do the work on droptree or genreal link

Comment: @RaedAbuGarbeiah you can still use a Treelist, just add an validator to ensure only one item is selected like so: http://www.benramey.com/2012/06/12/limit-selected-items-on-sitecore-multilist-field/. The regex will likely be this though: ^({[^}]+}|?){0,1}$.

Comment: you mean that no way to create single selected like droptree , and should use Treelist